# Style through components not created

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular

New question:

So, im looking for a way to toggle the display of two css classes called `hotel-in` and `hotel-out`.

These two classes will be in all of my 22 components. 
To toggle the display, im using a variable called `inHotel` that contains wherever the user is in a hotel or not.

when the variable is true, the `hotel-in` will be visible, and `hotel-out` be hidden.

when the variable is false, the `hotel-out` will be `visible`, and hotel-in be hidden.

How can i achieve this in the best manner?
Is it something general i could do in my main controller, that loads all the components?

Or do i have to do something spesific in every of the 22+ controllers?

---

Old question:

IN My main app component, where i have router outlets, i have the following:

```
<style *ngIf="inHotel">

  .hotel-in {
    display:block;
  }

  .hotel-out {
    display:none;
  }
</style>

   <style *ngIf="inHotel == false">

  .hotel-in {
    display:none;
  }

  .hotel-out {
    display:block;
  }
</style>
```

but when checking, even when that the inhotel is false, it dosent create that style.

The idea is that a function will toggle this inhotel.

and everything within the other components will have a div class `hotel-out` and `hotel-in` . and that will be visible/invisible depending of the inhotel class / style .

But for some reason it wont work.

What do i need to do to make this work?

edit 2:

I could use ngclass as mentioned, and get the hotelstate by every controller/route.

But in PHP and angular1, i had the option to put that piece of style code in the main file, ( where the router-outlet is located), and it would work as supposed.

The ideal would be that i only one place changes the display of `hotel-in` and `hotel-out` to toggle `display none` and `display block`.

then everything that had `hotel-in` and `hotel-out` in the other routes/views would act according to id.

edit3:

an example of html style that would be in different routes.

```
<div class=hotel-in">You are in hotel , more html...</div>
<div class="hotel-out">Something completely diff here </div>
```

edit3:

even when im style `*ngIf`, it wont produce any acual  tags with content on the page.

edit4:

It seems like i cant even post a style tag in the angular/angular-cli html. how come? and how can i make so i can make the style tag?

for some reason, even this wont come up to the page.

```
  <style>
.test {
  color:black; 
}
      </style>
```

Comment: HI .. Have you tried  use [NgClass] instead of NgIf ?

Comment: no , but what would this do? then i need to do ngClass on all my hotel classes, and import hotel state in each module controller?.

Comment: yes @incognito updated the question if that made any sence.

Comment: I could so in angular1 and PHP ( other way in PHP ofc). is it any other way @incognito i could toggle between two style states and make things easier for me?

Comment: what would best practice be @incognito? anyway, it wont produce the style output atm :/ . im afraid best practice would be getting state of hotel by every controller /route. and use ngclass. but that is alot of work.

Comment: generated new question @incognito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see change the style rules if they are written inside html page itself using https://github.com/deanmcpherson/angular-inline-style.

The idea is to rebuild style rules each time scope changes, by default this functionality is not provided by angular. But we can write a directive that links to style tag and recompiles it based on scope.

Comment: So a directive can ask server for hotel state and recompile whenever it’s needed ?

Comment: Yes, or even better if you can save the hotel state in $rootScope, then directive can observe the $rootScope variable and update the style sheet.

Comment: Nice idea. Could you help me create that? We could make a chat. Btw it’s angular 2/4 :)

Comment: I'm not really well versed with angular 2 but I would be happy to help.

Comment: it seems since i gave bounty away and i have less than 100rep, i cant create or chat here at stackoverflow. you have somewhere else?

Comment: You can contact me on skype tapas_bansal.